# Best practices by splitting to methods

Tags: java, typescript, coding-style

According to uncle Bob, it is a good practice to split the code into many small functions. I.a. imagine a 50 lines methods `root()`, it could be split to 10 methods of 5 lines. This is supposed to be good for code reuse.

I personally find it hard to read. Usually the 10 methods cannot be reused and have a sense only in the context of the `root()` method, they pollute the main class.

What I tend to is to create local function, this is pretty cool in typescript (harder in Java but also possible):

```
public root() {
  const subMethod1 = () => { return 'xxx'; }
  const subMethod2 = () => { return 'yyy'; }
  subMethod1() + ':' + subMethod2();
}
```

What do you think of it? What else can be done to avoid the multiplication of methods? (please don't answer to split into multiple classes, this is also a bad practice to have to many classes).

Thanks.

Comment: As a general rule, if someone gives you a style rule and you have issues with the rule that are themselves based on style (and, obviously, 'style' should lead to easy(ier) to read code, so if your problem with a style rule is that it makes your code hard to read, you've got a problem with a style rule based on a style argument) - then don't apply the rule to your code. Bob does a bad job explaining the why's and the examples shown tend to be, if anything, proof of the opposite. If it doesn't click for you, bob's extreme take (5 lines max method length) is certainly not an industry standard.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is by definition the a general guideline about what you should do in order to produce readable, efficient and reusable code *(minimize the technical debt)*.

A best practice is not application to every use case, but most. And all of them, uncle Bob's included, exists for a specific reason on a specific context.

Having a good understanding about the context of your project, you should be able to evaluate every "best practice" and decide if you should apply them or not.

For example, you could decide that the "good practice" of 80 character per line is irrelevant in your case and apply in your project a rule of 120 characters limitation.

[Some history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width#:%7E:text=As%20oded%20mentioned%2C%20this%20common,gets%20harder%20to%20read%20the) : The rule of 80 character per line was created based on the old displays that was only capable of displaying 80 characters on the same line. 80 character limitation was back then really important. Now with full HD monitors and IDE, we have more flexibility.

---

About the Bob rule itself, I have applied it in my engineering school for 5 years.

And yes, few times cuting the functions into smaller functions was "non-productive", but most of the time it's useful.

**Useful in what case ?**

- Having to create small functions makes you to go straight to the point and usually make you reconsider what you are doing. It's really hard to shrink a function. *Maybe there is a faster way to do it ?*
- One function do one job, which makes every function "simple"
- Cutting functions down makes it easier to spot the code that could be reused and also the useless things that are done sometimes
- It also teaches developer to be rigorous

---

**What about real life ?**

As @rzwitserloot said, I've not encountered any company implementing this rule in a strict way.

But you should consider what is implied by this rule *(short functions, remove the useless, structure the code ...)* as a general guidance more than trying to brutally apply it.

---

One example with fake code :

Consider the following function, that is treating a file in few steps :

- Read the content of the file, line by line
- Format the lines
- Send the formatted lines in a an email

---

```
function treatFile() {
  const lines = [];

  do {
    lines.push(l);
  } while (l = read());

  const builtMail = lines.map(x => ...);

  const obj = this.mailConnector.init();

  obj.sendMail(builtMail);

  return true;
}
```

You could turn this into :

```
function readFileByLine() {
  const lines = [];

  do {
    lines.push(l);
  } while (l = read());

  return lines;
}

function formatLines(lines) {
  return lines.map(x => ...);
}

function sendEmail(content) {
  const obj = this.mailConnector.init();

  obj.sendMail(content);
}

function treatFile() {
  const lines = readFileByLine();
  
  const builtMail = formatLines(lines);

  sendEmail(builtMail);

  return true;
}
```